# Spring cloud Stream not throwing exception

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring cloud stream with rabbitMQ.
I am trying to do the negative test by deleting the queue on runtime and post the message to the deleted queue.

```
source.queue2Source().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(queue4DTO).build());
```

I am listening message from queue 1 and posting the message to queue 2( deleted one). I was expecting that **above code** will throw an exception but it is not. Even the message from reading from queue 1 has been acknowledged. I have a dead letter queue on queue 1 and queue 2 but message not went into dlq.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the you are sending message to a `channel` defined by the `Source`. The channel actually does exist and is bridged via AMQPOutboundChannelAdapter to an exchange which by default will drop undeliverable messages.

Comment: Does it mean there is no way to catch this kind of error?

Comment: RabbitMQ does not consider such conditions (missing queue) as fatal by default; it silently drops such messages. If you set the producer property [errorChannelEnabled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_producer_properties) to true, failures to route messages to a queue will be published to the error channel.

Comment: @GaryRussell is error channel make a new queue in rabbitMQ like DLQ ?

Comment: No; it's a channel you can subscribe to to get error messages.